# Python regex substituting in only the first character when compiling from a list

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm creating a django filter for inserting 'a' tags into a given string from a list.

This is what I have so far:

```
def tag_me(text):
    tags = ['abc', 'def', ...]
    tag_join = "|".join(tags)
    regex = re.compile(r'(?=(.))(?:'+ tag_join + ')', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return regex.sub(r'<a href="/tag/\1/">\1</a>', text)
```

Example:

```
tag_me('some text def')
```

Returns:

```
'some text <a href="/tag/d/">d</a>'
```

Expected:

```
'some text <a href="/tag/def/">def</a>'
```

The issue lies in the regex.sub as it matches but returns only the first character. Is there a problem with the way I'm capturing/using \1 on the last line ?

Comment: As always, it's worth noting that [regular expressions are not the best tool for the job of parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/722121).

Comment: Yeah, duly noted. Originally I was looping over all tags but wondered if regex would be a performance booster...?

Comment: Is performance an issue? Even if it is, I sincerely doubt a regex will be significantly faster than a good HTML parser, and it is far more likely to be fragile.

Comment: @Lattyware: Ogre is parsing text and generating HTML, not (necessarily) parsing HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the sequence `(?: ...)` in the question specifically turns off capture.  See [`re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (about 1/5 thru page) which (with emphasis added) says:

> `(?:...)`   A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but **the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved** after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

As noted in previous answer, `'('+ tag_join + ')'` works, or use the suggested `"|".join(re.escape(tag) for tag in tags)` version if escapes are used in the target text.

Comment: Thanks! I missed what the start of the pattern does. Very thorough.

Answer (score 2):

You're capturing the `(.)` part, which is only one character.

I'm not sure I follow your regular expression - the simplified version `r'('+ tag_join + ')'` works fine for your example.

Note that if there's a chance of anything other than alphanumeric characters in your tag names, you'll want to do this:

```
tag_join = "|".join(re.escape(tag) for tag in tags)
```

Comment: @eyquem: Sorry, I don't understand your question...?

Answer (score 2):

Simply do

```
import re

def tag_me(text):
    tags = ['abc', 'def']
    reg = re.compile("|".join(tags).join('()'),
                       flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return reg.sub(r'<a href="/tag/\1/">\1</a>', text)

print '            %s' % tag_me('some text def')
print 'wanted:     some text <a href="/tag/def/">def</a>'
```

That's because you write a non-captured group `(?:....)` that you must then put this disturbing `(?=(.))` in front.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
def tag_me(text):
    tags = ['abc', 'def', ]
    tag_join = "|".join(tags)
    pattern = r'('+tag_join+')'
    regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return regex.sub(r'<a href="/tag/\1/">\1</a>', text)
```